How do I make a WSDL generated by a desktop proyect automatically, resemble another WSDL generated by a web service?
This is my first time as a poster since years of bein a lurker here. I'll also take this opportunity to thank all this community for their help consistently over the years. Thank you!
It's also my first time using anything related to SOAP, so sorry if there are any imprecisions, I'm understanding something wrong or I'm wanting to do something that it's not posible or done that way.
I need to mimic a WSDL from a client's WSDL, so I can consume their service and also that they can consume my service and we can exchange data/communications via functions. Their service is generated by a web project (URL ended in .asmx?WSDL) and mine should be generated by a desktop proyect (URL ended in ?wsdl, WCF project) so I can integrate it with other technologies as a middleware in Visual Basic .NET (using WinForms), being a web project the last resort.
For example, my requests look like this.
My petition
And they should look like this:
Client's petition
(Using SoapUI)
I can provide further information, like the code or App.config for my desktop aplication or the WSDL provided by the client if needed.
Thanks to you all in advance!
I've tried changing the service contracts and .config in general, changing them so they resemble the client's (we've been provided with them), tried to use code generating tools like svcutils.exe or wsdl.exe... But it doesn't seem to be the way.

You can use WCF Service Application to build the project. When the client needs to call them, just select the reference. Is the material you giving a direct reference to the WSDL documentation? If you can provide more information, I will help you further with the problem.

I basically have to stablish communication, so a client can know data from my database and I can know data from theirs. They've already exposed a service, but, I have to expose a service too. I know how to consume a service, the problem is exposing one that has the same WSDL.
To do that I did a project with WCF Service Application, I do not know if properly, but requests aren't the same (the ones in the images).
The only thing I have to do this solution is the clients published WSDL: http://solutionportal.tecalliance.net/OpenMessaging/openmessaging.asmx?WSDL

You wrote in the comment that your need is to access both databases.
I don't think it's really necessary to guarantee WSDL consistency. You can write a WCF server program and use sqlcommand to access the data.
Service1.svc
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
Public Function DataBase(ByVal connectstring As String,ByVal command As String) As Void Implements IService1.DataBase
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectstring)
Dim command As New SqlCommand(command, connection)

Try
    connection.Open()
    ' Manipulate the database
Finally
    connection.Close()
End Try
End Function
End Class

IService1.vb
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
   Function DataBase(ByVal connectstring As String,ByVal command As String) As Void Implements IService1.DataBase

   

End Interface

